# wrong value sent from i.getString

Tags: android, return-value

I have two activity , the first activity pass value to Second activity 
but the value is sent incorrectly
that is the code for onclick in first activity

```
 Intent nextScreen = new Intent(EgyptActivity.this, ViewRecord.class);

            nextScreen.putExtra("name", "1".toString() );
            startActivity(nextScreen);
```

second activity code is

```
Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();

        Receiving the Data
     String name = i.getString("name");
         Log.i ("name", name);
    String ne="1";
    Log.i ("ne", ne);
    if (name==ne)
    {Log.i ("info", ne);}
     if (name!=ne) 

     {Log.i ("info", "2");}

        }
```

LogCat

```
name: 1
ne: 1
info: 2
```

so please would any one tell me why the value name!=ne

Comment: You have to use if(name.equals(ne)). why downvote please explane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a proper string comparison use:

```
if (name.equals(ne))
{
    Log.i ("info", ne);
}
if (!name.equals(ne))
{
   Log.i ("info", "2");
}
```

Comment: no the problem "name" sent to second activity not equal "1" and not equal "ne" , while in logCat they are equal

Comment: @user2536135 - replace your if statements with what I posted. You are not correctly comparing the strings which is why they are showing as not equal

Comment: thanks dymmeh , it works with me

Comment: No problem. If it worked for you make sure to mark it as the correct answer by clicking the checkbox next to the answer.